# Using Django RequestFactory, this error is thrown: "Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured."

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

This is an example test from Django's documentation.

```
from django.test import RequestFactory, TestCase


class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()


    def test_hello(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/hello')
```

Running the test throws this error:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/suite.py", line 146, in _handleClassSetUp
    setUpClass()
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/pythonagent-my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1026, in setUpClass
    if not connections_support_transactions():
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/pythonagent-my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 991, in connections_support_transactions
    for conn in connections.all())
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/pythonagent-my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 226, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/pythonagent-my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 223, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/pythonagent-my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/pythonagent-my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 156, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/pythonagent-my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/myuser/dev/pythonagent-my_package/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 39, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

calling `django.conf.settings.configure()` doesn't change anything.

Comment: How are you running the test?

Comment: via pycharm which says the command line is: `python -m unittest simple_test.SimpleTest` in the dir the test resides

Comment: I would use the command line: python manage.py test . The management command  configures the environment before calling the test

Comment: I don't have a manage.py and I don't have a django app.  I just want to use the RequestFactory object from django's package.

Comment: A django test, by default, creates a test database if models are defined (unless otherwise configured).  In order to determine whether to create a database for a test, django looks at its settings. So as far as I know, django tests with a RequestFactory only make sense with a django app (even if only minimal).  You can create an empty app and see if that works.